# Why was the fact that Trump spends a lot of money on vacations edited out of this thread?

Tags: discussion, editing

[What is the US plan to finance spending and decrease deficit?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/what-is-the-us-plan-to-finance-spending-and-decrease-deficit)

This is a question regarding Trump's plan to finance his increased spending. The author mentions a number of ways Trump intends to increase spending. This originally included the fact that Trump spends a lot of time travelling and vacationing, [much more than other presidents](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/04/10/politics/donald-trump-obama-travel-costs/index.html), and this obviously classifies as spending, that must be financed by the budget, and is thus in line with the question being asked.

Yet, this part was edited out of the question by @Carpetsmoker.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

As the author of the edit wrote in the edit comment:

> I don't know if "take many vacations" is true, but it's not really applicable to the US federal budget as such (and therefore irrelevant)

I fully agree with that assessment. The US federal budget is measuring *trillions* of dollar. Personal travel expenses of the US president won't even make a dent. So the removed part was definitely a personal attack against Trump. We generally want to avoid such attacks when they don't contribute to the question, because we try to maintain a neutral point of view on this website.

Comment: Indeed my line of thinking. I don't think it's "definitely" a personal attack against Trump though, but it is likely perceived as such as Trump's travelling seems to be something of a hot issue. Better to be pro-active especially on hot-button issues.

Comment: What do you mean, "you don't know if he takes many vacations", when it is evidently true that he does, and has been proven? Further, even if it doesn't make a dent, pointing out that he takes many vacations still serves to point out Trump's general lavish philosophy. That is important to know, is it not?

Comment: @DinoSoru `pointing out that he takes many vacations still serves to point out Trump's general lavish philosophy. That is important to know, is it not` -> perhaps, but that's not really the point of this site. Questions should be narrow, reasonably neutral, and on-point. Pissing contests about Trump can be found ... everywhere. I personally would like to see this site as free as possible from that, and focus only on more objective matters. `it is evidently true that he does` -> I haven't really looked into this, and "many' is a very subjective word ;-)

Comment: "a billion here a billion there pretty soon you are talking about real money" it many never have been said, but it well reflects popular opinion of government opinion.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker This is not irrelevant to political policy because it is a small percentage of the budget. Political policies that cost less have been cut  to reduce spending. Currently one decision by the POTUS to reduce spending is to ban trans people from serving in the military because of medical costs. However the costs are estimated at [$8.4 million max,](https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_reports/RR1530.html) while Trump's trips are estimated at [$33 million a year.](http://www.politifact.com/punditfact/statements/2017/aug/23/david-frum/are-trumps-travels-imposing-historic-costs-taxpaye/)

Comment: @Braydon We all know that these are *both* cases where the cost argument is used as a pretext to criticize something one dislikes for far more subjective reasons than the cost for the taxpayer.

Comment: @Philipp These are the stated political reasons behind these views. I think it should be acceptable to evaluate them at face value. For instance ignoring any possible meaning other than to save money, this could easily be interpreted as the President prioritizing a bit of extra vacation over the service and dignity of thousands of Americans. This is a legitimate analysis of Trumps budgeting priorities.